# matrix inverse with modular entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

So I am dealing with a square $nxn$ matrix where the entries are all integers taken modulo $m$, we can assume $m$ to be a prime.  Can we make sense of an inverse of such a matrix?  Assuming of course that the matrix is invertible if we take the entries as real numbers.  And also obviously need to have the entries be invertible mod $m$, are those two things enough? Or would we need to ensure that every single entry we encounter in the process of row reducing is invertible mod $m$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matrix over the ring $\mathbb{Z}_m$, therefore is invertible iff its determinant is an invertible element of the ring, that is, iff $\det(A)$ is coprime to $m$, if $A$ is the matrix in question.

Comment: Thanks, I was guessing something like this might be the case but I didn't want to assume it.  Do you have a source or easy proof of this? Though it does seem fairly obvious now that you have said it.

Comment: @Elliot You could prove, in the same way as for real numbers, that $A \operatorname{adj}(A)=\det(A)I_n$, and that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, and then the conclusion follows.